# delete row in jquery without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using this code to delete a row ..  my code is working fine i am using datatables where in every row there is a button delete in front of them ..what I want is when a confirm dialog appears and the user press ok then it deletes the row and show the remaining rows in the datable without refresh .. i mean at that time if I press ok button it successfully deletes the row ..but the delete row remains there in the table until I refresh the page and then it removes from the table .. is that possible ?.. because I dont want from user that he after pressing delete  has to refresh to see whether the row is deleted or not ..

this is my view code usernames

```
         <td> <a href = "employesController/deleteEmploye/<?php echo  $row->emp_id ?>" 
             class = "deletes" >Delete</td>
```

my jquery code

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$(".deletes").click(function(e){
  var r =  confirm("are you sure you want to delete this");

   if (r==true){
    $this  = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(url, function(r){
        if(r.success){
            $this.closest("tr").remove();
        }
    })
   }else {
        return false;
       }

    });
     });
```

my controller

```
 function deleteEmploye($empid){

     $id = $empid;
    $this->load->model('employesModel');
    $query = $this->employesModel->deleteEmploye($id);
    return json_encode(array("success" => true));
```

model

```
  public function deleteEmploye($id){

         $this->db->where('emp_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->delete('employees');

        return $query->result();


 }
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more HTML

Comment: The `success` callback of `$.ajax` is passed the data returned from the AJAX call as its first parameter. Are you sure you are returning a JSON object with a `success` attribute that evaluates to true? Also, you are leaking `$this` as a global. Add `var`.

Comment: yeah i will show you my controller tooo

Comment: i updated my question ..and this is the error i am getting in firbug  response ..fatal error Call to a member function result() on a non-object localhost/.... in modal line 38

Answer (score 1):

First you need to verify that your if condition block is invoked. If it is invoked properly then try this one:

```
$this.parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebug (or a similar tool if you're not using firefox) to debug your ajax call. In the "network" tab you can see if your ajaxrequest is really sent, and what it returns.

Add console.log and console.dir statement to your code to find out what happens:

```
$.get(url, function(r){
    console.log("returned form ajax");
    if(r.success){
        console.log("successful, $this is now ");
        console.dir($this);
        $this.closest("tr").remove();
    }
}
```

This way you will find out, that your ajax does return, but
not with the result you expect: it only returns the data,
so looking up r.success will always fail.

The method .get you are using takes just two arguments: the
url, and a function that is only called in case of success!
So you don't need the if-statement at all:

```
$.get(url, function(r){
  $this.closest("tr").remove();
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/8RQQN/ for a fully working example.

---

Also: no not use **get** to delete stuff! Use **post** instead! You should also think about cross site request forgeries: somebody on a completely different site might add a link

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/employesController/deleteEmploye/4">free beer here</a>
```

to trick your users into deleting employees - without even noticing!

See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: ..and this is the error i am getting in firbug  response ..fatal error Call to a member function result() on a non-object localhost/.... in modal line 38

Comment: thank you for your tips but i thing i am doing something wrong in model..i am returning result .. am i doing right ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to send to a another script in php that delete this row and on confirn you can delete this row of you table

jquery

```
$.post("functions.php", { rowId: 1231 },
    function(data) {
        if (data == "ok")
            alert("the row has ben delete");
        else
            alert("the row is not delete");

});
```

php

```
<?php
    function delete_row(){
        //action to delete row in db
        // when the row has bes delete you can print ok
        echo 'ok';
        //if you have a error  you can print a message that you can managed y jquery
        echo "error 2121123"
    }
    if(isset($_post["rowId"]))
        delete_row($_post["rowId"]);
```